# Can't reference .NET Standard class library as NuGet package from .NET framework WPF App

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I want to share DTO's between a .NET Core REST API and a .NET Framework WPF app.
So I have put the DTO's into a separate .NET Standard 2.0 class library project/solution.

Reading up, I found that a NuGet package is the proper way to do this, so I configured the project to build a local NuGet package (I'm using VS 2019). The .nupkg files get created, no problems there.

When I add the NuGet package to my .NET Core 2.2 REST API project, everything works fine and I can reference the DTO's; still no problems.

But when I add the same NuGet package to my .NET Framework WPF app, the package is installed without errors but nothing seems to happen; the DTO class library namespace does not show up under References and can't be referenced in the code. I have re-targeted my WPF app to 4.7.2, as that is supposedly the only version that properly complies with .NET Standard 2.0 (?) but no joy.

The NuGet package does get added to the WPF app's packages.config file, but with targetFramework="net472", which doesn't seem right to me...

Note: I can manually add a reference to the DLL file in the bin directory of the DTO project - that works - but I shouldn't have to do that, should I?

What am I missing to get the NuGet package working?